# Display Multiple JQuery Tabs

Tags: jquery, function, tabs

I am trying to use several of this tabs function to display content on a single page. Except, right now, it only displays one div. Help please, thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/UtPxx

JAVA

```
$(function(){
    $('.tabs').hide();
    $('#tabs a').bind('click', function(e){
        $('#tabs a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.tabs:visible').hide();
        $(this.hash).show();
        $(this).addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
```

HTML

```
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="1" class="tabs">
Content 1
</div>
<div id="2" class="tabs">
Content 2
</div>

<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="3" class="tabs">
Content 3
</div>
<div id="4" class="tabs">
Content 4
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $('.tabs, .tabs2').hide();
    $('#tabs a, #tabs2 a').bind('click', function(e){
    var cl = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    if(cl=='tabs')
        {
        $('#tabs a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.tabs:visible').hide();
        }
        else
        if(cl=='tabs2')
        {
        $('#tabs2 a.current').removeClass('current');
        $('.tabs2:visible').hide();
        }
        $(this.hash).show();
        $(this).addClass('current');
        e.preventDefault();
    }).filter(':first').click();
});
</script>
<ul id="tabs">
<li><a href="#1">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">2</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="1" class="tabs">
Content 1
</div>
<div id="2" class="tabs">
Content 2
</div>
<div id="3" class="tabs">
Content 3
</div>

<ul id="tabs2">
<li><a href="#33">3</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="33" class="tabs2">
Content 3
</div>
<div id="4" class="tabs2">
Content 4
</div>
```

I have used 3 in both the tabs (to resolve another problem). When you click 3 in any of the tab, it will always display 3rd div of first tab because when this.hash is executed, it looks for #3 and every time it will return the first element with id 3. So I have changed #3 to #33 in the second tab.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I was hoping not needing to duplicate the script because of the possibility of adding more individual tabs.

Comment: I have changed JS code in my previous answer. Have a look at that. In my opinion you have to write conditions in the JS itself.

Comment: I am really looking for something similar to the following link, where the same tab can be used multiple times without further edits to the script. I am just not sure what line I'm looking for.
http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/jquery.idTabs.min.js

Comment: The link you have shared is another jquery plugin. Using that plugin will require you again to change the JS code to suit your requirement of having more than 1 set of tabs on 1 page. Looking at the code I am not sure that you can use multiple sets of tabs on 1 page without changing the JS code.